# Custom shortcut does't work!

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

I would like to have a shortcut for a command:

```
sudo nautilus "/"
```

I tried to set it in Keyboard->Shortcuts->Custom Shortcuts but it didnt work.
I also created shell file with this command and put it(`sh myfile.sh`) there but it also didnt work.
When I set there only `nautilus` it works but this is not what I want.

Does anyone know how can I create shortcuts for a custom command like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `sudo` will require you to enter your password, it probably isn't "working" because you're not running it in a terminal.

To run from the GUI instead, you should use `gksudo` rather than plain `sudo`. This will present a graphical dialog for you to enter your password with, to authenticate running as root.

Also note, that it probably won't work as you expect. You'll want the `--no-desktop` option passed to nautilus, otherwise you'll see the root user's background rather than yours.

Comment: "gksudo" works very well for me. Thank you dobey!